# Reconstruction of java command line arguments

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-interface

Is there a way to reconstruct the command line arguments passed to Java within a Java program, including the JVM options and classpath option?

I have a Java program that needs to restart the JVM and manipulate its bootclasspath (i.e. trying to override some system classes).  I use the `libc` `system` method to invoke the new JVM.

I'm open for better approaches, but Java agents isn't an option.

Comment: I'm really curious about what you are trying to do here...

Comment: @trashgod, no it's not available for reuse

Comment: @alex, I'm trying to get some (minor) Java 7 specific features in a plugin environment, with reducing the installation instructions.  Check out http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a file that has these properties just like the Eclipse [ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file and NetBeans [conf](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf) files. That way you just read these properties and spawn the new Java process with these properties.

Back to your question, this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518213/read-java-jvm-startup-parameters-eg-xmx) should do

Comment: Thanks! `RuntimeMZBean.getInputArguments()` solves the problem quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that futzing with the bootclasspath is generally a poor idea. But...

Grab the code for "java.c" - the C program that compiles down to java.exe. You'll find that it just uses the JNI Invocation API to construct a JVM and call the main method. You could modify and re-compile this to look for particular exit codes, etc. and loop around and re-launch the JVM if required.

Alternatively, Eclipse does this (or at least used to), but having one Java program construct the command line (from a props file, etc.) and launch a sub-process. Again, it hooked the sub-process exit code and used that to decide whether or not to re-launch a new sub-process.

Answer (score -1):

Err... modifying a whole core java class at *runtime* is a very very bad idea.

Whats wrong with subclassing here? Are you trying to modify an external library, add functionality, or be lazy?

Comment: Welcome to the Internet, friend.