# How to I get programmatic access to check -Xms -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize JVM argument values?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read Java JVM startup parameters (eg -Xmx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518213/read-java-jvm-startup-parameters-eg-xmx)

I'm running an application on a Tomcat server, and I want to access the values of the `-Xms -Xmx` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM argument values so that I can log them for help with debugging.

I've tried to find these arguments listed in `System.properties`, and using `System.getEnv()`, but they are not there. Is there another way to get them, or, alternately, is their lack of presence in `System.properties` and `System.getEnv()` an indication that these options have not been set?

Comment: That's a helpful solution, although the Runtime.totalMemory() idea listed below is a good supplement to it, because it is helpful in the case where -Xms is not set, but you still want to see how much memory is there by default (as turned out to be the case with my issue).

Comment: Why do it programmatically? It's set in the Tomcat configuration. Just copy that on every startup.

Comment: Because I do not control the servers, and do not have access to the Tomcat configuration without having to track down and bother system administrators.

Answer (score 4):

What about [Runtime.totalMemory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory%28%29) (of course if you have permissions, or security is disabled) ?

Another workaround is to search for the command line that has started the tomcat and parse it. In linux is easy, but in windows...

Comment: This is for Xms. For Xmx `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can get basic information from the Runtime class, including total, maximum and free memory; refer to [Runtime JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for specifics.

If that isn't enough info, you can use the Management extensions to get a lot more information about current and peak memory usage in each of the memory pools. You can browse all of the available information for a running JVM using the MBeans tab on [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html), which is included with the Oracle JDK. Specifically, look at the MBeans with object name `java.lang:type=Memory`, and `java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=*`.

Once you've identified the MBeans with the information you need, you can access them programatically using the [ManagementFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) class. This allows generic access to all MBeans (you can make your own), but has convenience methods for some of the MBeans provided by the platform, including:

- [getMemoryMXBean()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryMXBean%28%29)
- [getMemoryPoolMXBeans()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getMemoryPoolMXBeans%28%29)